# Chave primária na tabela associativa(Muitos para muitos)

Tags: sql, tabela-html, normalização

Boa noite.

Tenho a seguinte pergunta no relacionamento N para N. As chaves estrangeiras se tornam uma chave primária composta da tabela associativa. Correto?

Isto me garante que não haja repetição entre as tuplas? Pois eu penso que mesmo elas compondo a chave primária pode haver repetição, então suponho em adicionar um outro campo de chave primária para garantir a integridade (func_projetoID). Ou meu pensamento está errado?

Obrigado por ler. Saudações.[image: Imagem exemplificando]

Comment: Isso é exatamente o que é feito num sistema real.
Só que nem sempre é usado chave composta. Na teoria, na modelagem, você pode apresentar esta ideia que passará sem erros. Mas na implementação, o que se vê é uma `pk` func_projetoID, uma coluna `fk` func_id e outra `fk` projeto_id.
Enfim, seu pensamento está correto.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: @AndrewRibeiro Escreve uma resposta, por favor.

Comment: @Leonardo +1, mas, por favor, escreva um título mais significativo. Sua pergunta é excelente. Modelagem de banco de dados é, talvez, a parte mais importante de um projeto de software. Ainda me surpreende não termos tantas perguntas referentes a isso. Precisamos documentar bem as perguntas e respostas, porque elas com certeza vão servir pra pessoas que tiveram a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na teoria, seu pensamento está totalmente correto. Na prática, apenas parcialmente.

O que se vê na prática (o que é um pouco decepcionante) são os desenvolvedores ignorarem a criação da chave composta por questões de implementação.

Mas com relação a ideia da chave primária precedendo as outras duas colunas é muito comum de se observar.

Ficaria algo assim:

`pk` func_projeto_id

`fk` func_id

`fk` func_projeto

Para concluir, adicionar uma chave primária na tabela associativa é uma ideia bacana e muito comum de se encontrar na maioria dos softwares.

Answer (score 2):

> Tenho a seguinte pergunta no relacionamento N para N. As chaves
>   estrangeiras se tornam uma chave primária composta da tabela
>   associativa. Correto?

Correto. Relacionamentos N para N devem gerar uma tabela própria que terá um relacionamento 1 para N com cada uma delas. 
A chave primária desta tabela será composta pelas chaves primárias das tabelas que geraram esta nova.

> Isto me garante que não haja repetição entre as tuplas?

Sim não haverá repetição entre as tuplas, pois a chave será composta pelas chaves primárias de cada uma das tabelas, e por definição as chaves são únicas.

Abaixo segue uma imagem de um slide que o meu professor utilizou para lecionar. Acho que ilustra bem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**NOTA** : A minha resposta é com base acadêmica e não prática. Ainda não tive a oportunidade de trabalhar em um sistema real.

Comment: Valeu. Obrigado pela resposta.
Eu estava tentando achar um jeito de quebrar a integridade e consegui. Supondo que um médico realize consultas com um determinado paciente. O ID do médico e o do paciente terão repetições no BD por causa das várias consultas ao longo do ano, o que causará inconsistência na base de dados. Em casos assim, que haverá várias interações dos mesmos elementos é necessário fundamentar a chave primária com mais um atributo além das foreign keys.

Comment: Corrigam-me se eu estiver errado. Mas se vc quiser guardar histórico de consultas. Vai precisar de um atributo extra. Neste caso a data. O que vc disse é a definição de entidade associativa. Vc não conseguiria sequer salvar no banco, por se tratar da mesma chave. Ele iria sobreescrever. Logo não haveria repetição de tuplas contendo (id_medico,id_paciente).

Comment: Exato, foi isso que eu observei. Por isso achei melhor colocar uma chave primária para a tabela associativa e não as foreign keys, justamente para o caso da repetição. Vlw